# Possibility of vulnerability in Logback

Tags: android, security, log4j, logback

We have received an alert report regarding a vulnerability in log4j. I would like to know if we can have the same issue with logback

[Link to the report](https://www.cert.ssi.gouv.fr/alerte/CERTFR-2021-ALE-022/)

Versions in our project:

```
com.github.tony19:logback-android : 2.0.0  
org.slf4j:slf4j-api: 1.7.30
```